# How to selectively disable intellisense in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I do NOT want to turn intellisense off.  I just want to lose all the Win32 functions, keywords, etc.  I keep typing short varialbles like "aL" and when I hit space intellisense auto-completes to to be ALERT_SYSTEM_INFORMATIONAL, which then has to be either ctrl-Z'd or backspace'd over to get rid of it.

I do want it auto-complete my own defined classes and functions (this is for C++).

Everything was working exactly as I wanted it two days ago.  But I had to connect to Microsoft to renew my license (I did NOT accept any updates) and it started then.

It is seriously disrupting my workflow.  How do I get back to where I was before I signed in to renew my license!??

Comment: I changed the completion shortcut, so I have to hit tab to accept the completion. I was frustrated by the same thing.

Comment: [MS Developer Community - Add support for excluding files from Intellisense/related feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-support-for-excluding-files-from-intellisenser/406303)  _"...I’m reactivating this item and putting it back under Review. It’s gotten some votes recently and I think there may be enough interest to consider it....May 27, 2020 ..."_  Still open last comment Dec 15, 2022

Comment: Currently VS does not have this function, if you need it, I suggest you report to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).